# Using mockito to mock a service with generic methods within

Tags: java, generics, junit, mockito

Assuming that I have this repository

```
@Repository public class GenericHistoryRepositoryImpl implements GenericHistoryRepository {

    @Autowired  private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
            @Override   public Historiable create(Historiable historiableObject, String collectionName) {
                mongoTemplate.save(historiableObject, collectionName);
                return historiableObject;   }


    @Override   public <T extends Historiable> T get(String id, Class<T> collectionClass, String collectionName) {
                Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(id));
    return mongoTemplate.findOne(query, collectionClass, collectionName);
            } }
```

And I have this test in which I have to mock the repository, but I can't figure out how

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GenericHistoryServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private GenericHistoryRepository genericHistoryRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private GenericHistoryService genericHistoryService = new GenericHistoryServiceImpl();
  

      
    @Test   
        public <T extends Historiable> void getHistoryOk2() throws NotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException {
            String id = "1"

;
        String collectionName = HistoriableCollections.HISTORIABLE_SHIPMENT_REQUEST;
        ShipmentRequest a = mock(ShipmentRequest.class);
        Class<? extends Historiable> clazz = ShipmentRequest.class;
    when(genericHistoryRepository.get(any(String.class), eq(clazz), collectionName)).thenReturn(createExample());
            
    
        HistoriableDTO result = genericHistoryService.get(id, HistoriableCollections.HISTORIABLE_SHIPMENT_REQUEST);
    
        //      verify(genericHistoryRepository, times(1)).get(id, any(), HistoriableCollections.HISTORIABLE_SHIPMENT_REQUEST);
    
        assertThat(result, is(notNullValue()));          
        assertThat(result.getId(), is(notNullValue()));
    }
```

Keep in mind that Historiable is an abstract class

```
public abstract class Historiable {

    public abstract String getParentId();

}
```

And this extends Historiable

```
@Document(collection = HistoriableCollections.HISTORIABLE_SHIPMENT_REQUEST)
public class ShipmentRequest extends Historiable {

    private String id;
    
    @Indexed
    private String parentId;

...

}
```

**My problem is with the "when" sentence defining the behaviour of the repository mock. It has generic methods that I don't know how to mock**

```
Class<? extends Historiable> clazz = ShipmentRequest.class;
    when(genericHistoryRepository.get(any(String.class), eq(clazz), collectionName)).thenReturn(createExample());
```

I'm getting

The method thenReturn(capture#1-of ? extends Historiable) in the type OngoingStubbing<capture#1-of ? extends Historiable> is not applicable for the arguments (ShipmentRequest)

```
private ShipmentRequest createExample() {
        ShipmentRequest history = new ShipmentRequest();
        history.setId("1");

        return history;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your when clause is the problem.

Inside the `when` you should define when to match and after that you state what should be returned.

Your when statement starts good by stating you want to match any `String` passed as first argument, but as a second argument you are passing a mock so that means that it will only trigger if that specific mock is passed as second argument (which I don't think is happening).

You can change the second argument to: `any(Class.class)`

For the third argument you can state that you want it to be equal to `collectionName` by using: `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers#eq(T)`

Comment: That seems to work, but I have furthers problems with another service. I think it will be clearer if a ask a new question instead. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your test class you can have something like this

```
public class TestClass {

@Mock
GenericHistoryRepository genericHistoryRepository;

@InjectMock
MongoTemplate  mongoTemplate;


@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

}
```

`@InjectMock` will inject the depedency of your mock.

Comment: Sure, I already have that... My problem is with the "when" sentence defining the behaviour of the repository mock. It has generic methods that I don't know how to mock. I'll update the question tu clarify that